# python openpyxl insert_cols changes merge-cells and styles

Tags: python, openpyxl

I tried to insert a column into an excel.

However, the style of cells has been changed

CODE:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('xt3.xlsx')
sheet = wb.worksheets[0]

sheet.insert_cols(0)
[enter image description here][1]wb.save("filename.xlsx")
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hl5QY.png

issues on bitbucket: https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/1098/bugs-insert_cols-changes-merge-cells-and

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Losing merged cells border while editing Excel file with openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38734044/losing-merged-cells-border-while-editing-excel-file-with-openpyxl)

Comment: Please try this method that I showcased here.It works for keeping the Merged Cells but I'm not sure if it works for keeping the style too:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51620536/openpyxl-adding-new-rows-in-excel-file-with-merged-cell-existing/51980431#51980431

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging I wrote this code in openpyxl and xlrd/xlwt/xlutils.
Support both xls and xlsx.

**Before**
[image]

**After**
[image]

The key is to use `copy` and generate coordinate.
Code is [here](https://github.com/BennyThink/tools/blob/master/xls/xls.py)

Answer (score 1):

This code will insert 3 columns; It keeps the background color but not all of the borders.

```
merged_cells_range = ws.merged_cells.ranges
for merged_cell in merged_cells_range:
    merged_cell.shift(3,0)
ws.insert_cols(1,3)
```

[image]

Comment: You can change the number of columns to insert by changing the '3' from : `merged_cell.shift(3,0)` and  `ws.insert_cols(1,3)`